# How should I calibrate the image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have hundreds of images like attached, and I need to calibrate them into the real-world units like millimeter. I have read spatial calibration demo [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/9678/spatial_calibration_demo.m), but I can't draw a line every time when analyzing the image, in order to generate the calibration factor. How can I adjust the code in a loop? Thanx!!!

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "like that"? have they all been taken at the same distance and the same focal length?

Comment: Thanks @Piglet! Which "like that" do you mean? I can't find it in my question. Anyway, those pictures were taken at the same distance (I marked the distance) and under the same focal length. But during the photographing, the camera was removed and reset several times. So I guess the angle and the distance may vary a bit. That's why I need to calibrate the picture.

Comment: like attached sorry... if you have the same distance, same focal length and focus the same height 1 calibration is sufficient for all images for most applications. what do you want to do?

Comment: @Piglet Just in case the camera moves when I'm taking pictures. So I want to calibrate every image. I want to write a script to detect the cross on the right side of the image and define the distance between two crosses as 1 cm. Then calculate the calibration factor as 1cm devided by the pixel distance between two crosses. Then use the calibration factor to calibrate the area and radii that I got by calling `regionprops`.

Comment: you should use more than 1cm to reduce errors. also consider fitting a circle into the Petri dish. I guess they have a standard diameter. for future images use a better calibration target. like simple markers (black round spots on white background or similar) with known distance. detecting the mm paper on the right is not trivial. your entire setup is let's say sub-optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to record the scale manually and then save that value for later use whenever you need to use a particular image in the future. If so, then you should group you photos together into a single folder (or in batches), loop through each photo, record the scale, save the scale to an array, then save the array as a text file that can be referenced later.

If you have a bunch of photos in a folder then here is a script that will loop through all the photos and allow you to click to set the scale in each. If you use the ginput function you can click two adjacent corners of the large grid squares, calculate the distance between the points and this will give you the number of pixels per cm. Each iteration of the loop will save the scale to a value in an array that corresponds to that photo. Later, if you need the scale for photo 'nDss7.jpg', look up the name in the list of photos, then use the index to reference the corresponding index in the scale array.

```
disp('Select folder...')
path = uigetdir;
list = dir([path, filesep, '*.jpg']); 
scale = zeros(length(list), 1);

for ii = 1 : length(list)
    im = imread([path, filesep, list(ii).name]); 
    imshow(im)
    hold on

    ok = 0;
    while ok == 0

        disp('Click corners of large grid square')

        % Input corners of large grid squares
        [xCorner1, yCorner1] = ginput(1);
        plot(xCorner1, yCorner1, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 20)

        [xCorner2, yCorner2] = ginput(1);
        plot(xCorner2, yCorner2, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 20)

        % Check the points are ok
        choice = questdlg('Are the corners accurate?',...
            'Verification',...
            'Yes', 'No', 'Yes');
        % Handle response
        switch choice
            case 'Yes'
                scale(ii) = sqrt((xCorner1 - xCorner2)^2 + (yCorner1 - yCorner2)^2); % scale in pixels per cm
                disp(['Pixels per cm = ', num2str(scale(ii))])
                ok = 1;
            case 'No'
                disp('Try again')
                close all
                imshow(frame)
                hold on
                continue
        end
    end

    hold off

end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Sam! Sorry that until now I have time to really try your code. It works very well! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Ziming, I'm glad it worked. If I answered your question then you can mark this as the answer and it might help others with the same problem